# Getting the last data update time of a specific table in Oracle

Tags: oracle

How can I get the last update time of table, i.e. at what time the last operation (insert/update/delete) was performed on a table in oracle?

I have tried using:

```
SELECT MAX(SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN)) from mytablename;
```

But this gives me an ORA-08181 error ("specified number is not a valid system change number").

Comment: Why do you want to know that?

Comment: I have many tables and want to show a graphical interface to Admin so that he can have all the details without doing any thing technically(firing a query etc)

Answer (score 2):

You should change the order of MAX and SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP

```
SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(MAX(ORA_ROWSCN)) from mytablename;
```

This might still fail if it has been long time since table has been modified, but should work for active tables.

Answer (score 1):

The database collects automatically the number of insert/update/delete operations, and the time of last modification. You can query it from the view `USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS`, `ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS` or `DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS`, columns `INSERTS`, `UPDATES`, `DELETES` and `TIMESTAMP`. Note that the data is collected in memory internally, and persisted later, meaning if you query the view, you may see outdated results. If you want the actual data, first you need to persist the data by flushing it to disk from memory with:

```
begin
  dbms_stats.flush_database_monitoring_info;
end;
/
```

Then query the view:

```
select timestamp from user_tab_modifications where table_name = '&table_name';
```

Comment: Cool, I have never come across those. But it's not really "automatically". [From the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-97603337-F3D8-4FC4-ADE0-E49200F6EE4E.htm): "*These views are populated only for tables with the `MONITORING` attribute*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Depends on the version, and I really hope the OP is not on an ancient, unsupported version. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables005.htm - *"Starting with Oracle Database 11g, the MONITORING and NOMONITORING keywords have been deprecated and statistics are collected automatically."*. I pasted the link to the 11g documentation intentionally, because the 12c document mentions `MONITORING` and `NOMONITORING` was deprecated, but does not specify the version. Above feature works even when the table is set to `NOMONITORING`, as that is simply ignored.